# Synced Realm not being loaded on launch

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

I'm attempting to use Realm Object Server in my ios app. I am hosting it on AWS, and I can successfully read and write to it. However, I'm having a problem accessing the synced realm after launching my app. On launch, I have a login view controller (very similar to the one provided in the example app)

After authenticating successfully, I want to access the synced Realm to decide which view controller to present.

```
@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard userInputValid() else {
        return
    }
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.logInButton.isHidden = true
    SyncUser.authenticate(with: Credential.usernamePassword(username: userNameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, actions: []), server: syncAuthURL!, onCompletion: { user, error in
        guard let user = user else {
            self.presentError(error: error as! NSError)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.logInButton.isHidden = false
            return
        }

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
            syncConfiguration: (user, self.syncServerURL!),
            objectTypes: [Dot.self, Mod.self]
        )

        let realm = try! Realm()
        // realm.objects(Dot.self).count == 0 here even though there is a Dot object persisted in the server
        // When I access the realm later in the app (e.g in a viewDidAppear of another controller) the object is there
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let vc = DotCollectionViewController(nibName: "DotCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navVC
    })
}
```

I have validated reads and writes to the synced Realm and found something peculiar: the realm seems to have a fileURL of null even when I'm able to write data successfully. I am accessing the realm in other parts of my app using `let realm = try! Realm()` and when I do `print(realm.configuration.fileURL)` I always get nil, even for valid synced Realms.

So my question is, do I have to wait some period of time for the synced Realm to be accessible? If so, how would I go about doing this? Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected that the `fileURL` of a synced Realm's configuration be `nil`, since the file location is managed my Realm and inaccessible to the user (you).

When opening a synced Realm for the first time on a device, the Realm will be accessible as soon as a valid `SyncUser` exists, provided by the `SyncUser.authenticate(...)` callback. However, its contents will be populated asynchronously, which is why `realm.objects(Dot.self)` is empty when immediately opening the Realm, but later gets the objects from the server.

If it's important to wait for that data to be available before proceeding with a part of your app, there are two ways Realm is working on to do that in the near future:

- [The ability to download a full Realm in a single operation](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4150)
- The ability to detect if there are any remote changes not present in the local Realm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in my app, I'm loading a collectionview based off a synced realm. What would be the best way to wait for the realm to be populated before loading? I can use `Thread.sleep()` but that's a hack, obviously. I also don't want to have a timer task constantly checking for UI updates.

Comment: You should be using collection notifications to know when changes come in, whether from sync, other processes, or other threads.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by collection notifications?